# Dictionary only retrieve the previous value not updated with the new value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

When I tap did tap marker its give me the current marker but when new marker add it doesn't append it, Its append it after newer child added.

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.infoWindow.removeFromSuperview()
            self.locationMarker = nil
            self.locationMarker = marker
            var markerData: NSDictionary?
            if let data = marker.userData! as? NSDictionary {
                markerData = data
            }
            print(markerData as Any)

            self.infoWindow.markData = markerData
            self.infoWindow = self.loadNiB()
            if let keyData = markerData?["key"] {
                self.keyDataStored = keyData
                markerData = nil
            }
            guard let location = self.locationMarker?.position else {
                print("locationMarker is nil")
                return
            }

            self.infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.point(for: location)
            self.infoWindow.center.y = self.infoWindow.center.y - self.sizeForOffset(view: self.infoWindow)
            UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.25, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
                self.view.addSubview(self.infoWindow)
            }, completion: nil) 
        return false
    }
```

the result of print(markerData as Any) is

```
Optional({
    Vote = 0;
    key = "-LVIje0829RH0EkwUuiz";
    latitude = "37.33233141";
    longitude = "-122.0312186";
})
```

for the old child

but if I added new child lets mark it with the xchild  the result is

```
Optional({
    latitude = "37.49707671";
    longitude = "-122.31324792";
})
```

if I added new child again let's say its a ychild  the xchild will be updated and become

```
Optional({
        Vote = 0;
        key = "-LVICnM6l5TMdsqkpP70";
        latitude = "37.49707671";
        longitude = "-122.31324792";
    })
```

and the ychild will be missing the vote and key until new one added

Comment: Please add more description and debug response also if possible.

Comment: Mostly it could be because of self.keyDataStored = keyData, it will contains last data only. probably you need to use addVaule API.

Comment: thank you four your comment here is some pics of my debug area https://drive.google.com/file/d/11tOFr1F7Zb7N_zp6ZhWAZ_0JhH6Ro8s1/view?usp=sharing that before added new child

Comment: and that after I added a new child https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bDnfqd_GhdtUG30E2EWlS-ZKFVvTtCNO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Firstly make sure your keys are different each time you are appending into dictionary.Secondly, please clearly state that what you want to achieve.